# Matplotlib yaxis lines

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I've been tinkering a bit with the **`.grid()`** function in `matplotlib`, trying to put lines in the **`y`**-axis of a graph bar.

But I'm not getting what I would like, which is to have just lines in the `y`-axis and also that the lines don't show in the bar graphs (right now I'm getting in both y and x axes and I can see the lines in the bars).

For a MWE I'm calling this function where **`comp`** is a list of lists of integers, in which I am operating, **`args`** is just the names of the `xlabels`, **`ctype`** is `len( comp )` and **`filename`** and **`title`** are just strings to name stuff.

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def drawMedian(ctype, filename, title, yaxis, comp, *args):
    plt.switch_backend('Qt4Agg')
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
    medians = []
    for v in comp:
       medians.append(np.median(v))
    col = ['r','b','g','y','c','m']
    ax.grid(b=True, linestyle='-', which='both', linewidth=2, alpha=0.3)
    ax.bar( range(1, (int(ctype))+1),  medians, align='center', color=col[0: int(ctype)] )
    plt.title(title)
    labels = [i for i in args]
    plt.ylabel(yaxis +' (median)' )
    plt.xticks(range(1, (int(ctype)) + 1), labels)
    plt.savefig(filename+' (median).png', bbox_inches = 'tight')
    plt.xticks()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Still getting this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `.grid()` call signature:

```
  grid( self,
           b     = None,
           which = 'major',
           axis  = 'both',
           **kwargs
           )

Sets the axes grids on or off;

( b ) is a boolean.  ( For MATLAB compatibility, also may be a string {'on'|'off'} )

                  If b == None and ( len(kwargs) == 0 ), toggle the grid state.

                  If **kwargs are supplied, it is assumed
                                            that you want a grid
                                            and b is thus set to True.

( which ) can be 'major' (default),
                 'minor', or
                 'both' to control whether major tick grids,
                                           minor tick grids,
                                           or both are affected.

( axis )  can be 'both' (default),
                 'x', or
                 'y' to control which set of gridlines are drawn.

( **kwargs ) are used to set the grid line properties, eg:

                 ax.grid( color     = 'r',
                          linestyle = '-',
                          linewidth = 2
                          )
```

### Solution:

```
ax.grid( ...,  axis = 'y', ... ) #  consider modifying ( zorder ) in case other visual ordering is expected
```

Comment: Yeah I've tried that but I'm still getting this http://i.imgur.com/yASpBQk.png , maybe there is no way to do what I would want.

Comment: What are **`.zorder`** values used?

Comment: 2 at the bars and 1 at the grid